# Validate Content-Type of office file when office is not installed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate `Content-Type` of office files, for example a `Word` file.
I read the `Content-Type` in the server side and validate it against a white list of content types.
The problem is when there is no office installed on the machine I receive

`Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Another thing is that currently I use a hard coded white list of content types  which I don't like, since that list can be out of date over time.

Comment: Why don't you check the extension of the uploaded file and see whether or not it is `.doc` or `.docx`? Or maybe I don't really get your question

Comment: because in the world of security looking at the file extension is not enough....

Comment: Check the Hex header of the uploaded file. See https://www.datadoctor.biz/data_recovery_programming_book_chapter14-page2.html .Be aware of that `.doc` and `.docx` have different headers.